# Accept facebook closed group request thorugh facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there any way in facebook graph api to accept requests to join closed facebook group though graph api.
I checked documentation i can see that one can send invitation through graph api, I just want to know if admin can accept requests through facebook graphi api or not ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no API for that. You can´t even send an invitation, that´s only for "App Groups":

> An app access token can be used to invite people (if they are an
>   admin, developer, or tester of the app) to a group created by that
>   app.

App groups are deprecated though.